# Searching string in php, search field contains white space

Tags: php, whitespace

This is my code

```
<div style="display:inline-block; ">    
<?php $a = strtolower($criteria); if (strpos($a, 'fits models from: 11/2000') !== false) { 
     echo 'Fits models from 2000,'; } ?> </div>
```

I have a problem with the white space.
It finds the string if I use only 'fits models from' or if I use '11/2000', but not the two combined. I need them combined or else it's usless.

EDIT:
I can't do something like this:

```
<?php $a = strtolower($criteria); 
if (strpos($a, 'fits models from')  !== false)  
if (strpos($a, '11/2000') !== false) { 
    echo 'Fits models from 2000,'; } ?> </div>
```

because I want to use it to seperate key factors from a text, which is the car model, from the rest and output that information.
If $criteria says 'fits model from 11/2000, but only fits model until 06/2002' then it will output 'fits model from 2000', 'fits model until 2000', 'fits model from 2002', 'fits model until 2002'.

Comment: `but not the two combined` : What do you mean by this? can you write that combined string? and Where does the white space come to the question?

Comment: I can't write 'fits models from: 11/2000', then it echoes nothing. I can write the first part of the sentence 'fits models from:' and the second part '11/2000' and both times it echoes what I'm after. The white space is 'fits models from:(whitespace)11/2000'

Comment: In my case, it's reversed... [see](https://eval.in/821240)

Comment: That's weird. This is the three cases I have tried to use. In my case the first two options work, but I can't use them (see edit of post), and third won't work.. [this is the format](https://eval.in/821249)

Comment: I can see that case 3, which is the case I want to use, works on that site, but it isn't working in my code, and I have no idea why.. Anyways, thanks for your help @ShaunakShukla

Comment: there must be any junk character in between. try to change the encoding from UTF8 to ANSII.

Answer (score 0):

To identity an unknown character:

1. find the string encoding (probably UTF-8 in your case)
2. extract a short substring with the character
3. split it into bytes and display them in hexadecimal
4. looking at the encoding table, find what character it is with the byte(s) used to encode it

example with the string: `"a:\xe2\x80\x85b"` that looks like `a: b` but with a smaller space.

```
$str = "a:\xe2\x80\x85b"; // I wrote \xe2\x80\x85 only to set $str and to show a working code,
                          // but here I don't know what are the values of these bytes  

preg_match('~:(.*?)b~us', $str, $m); // shortest substring between : and b

echo implode(' ', array_map(function ($b) { return dechex(ord($b)); }, str_split($m[1])));

// e2 80 85
```

I obtain the 3 bytes `e2` `80` `85`, then I search if it represents one or several characters in the [unicode table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) and I find: `U+2005     e2 80 85    FOUR-PER-EM SPACE`

Conclusion: the unknown character is a `FOUR-PER-EM SPACE` (unicode point: U+2005) and needs the 3 bytes `e2 80 85` to be encoded in UTF-8. So I can write it `"\xe2\x80\x85"` in a double quoted string.