# Replace junk character in strpos search

Tags: php, strpos

I'm searching through an outputted text which gets elements from different tables, so each $criteria is unique. It's about 1,5 million unique articles.

The $criteria is all information about a product, but I'm working on only showing what I think is keyinformation.

I'm using this code:

```
  <?php  
$criteria = 'Fits models until: 05/2009; diameter: 815mm; mount: front; 
etcetcetc.';

 $a = strtolower($criteria); 
if (stripos($a, 'Fits models until: 05/2009') !== false) { 
 echo 'Fits models until 2009'; } ?>
```

The problem I have is that the space between the colon and the next element have a junk character (e.g diameter:JUNKCHARACTER815mm;), but only shows as an blank space. Is there any way to work around the junk character/blank space?

EDIT:
This question is not a duplicate of my former [Searching string in php, search field contains white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715209/searching-string-in-php-search-field-contains-white-space) because this time around I got help figuring out it was a junk character, and not just a normal white space.

Comment: Find what is this character and replace it systematically with a simple space. What is the problem?

Comment: where is JUNKCHARACTER i m unable to see..?

Comment: I can't replace it. All the information it gets is from a database which every provider of carparts use in Norway, and I can't figure out what the junk character is either.

Comment: The junk character only appears as a white space. I know there's a junk character there because the code works fine [here](https://eval.in/821342) but not on my live server, which is a excact duplicate